# How to kick somebody out on socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am on a websocket (socket.io) and I want to be able to force disconnect on a given user. I use this on my server file:

```
// kickout
  socket.on('kickout', (sckid) => {   //sckid is the socket.id of the kicked-out user
     io.to(sckid).emit('kicked');
    });
  });
  
  // kicked out
  socket.on('kicked', () => {
   socket.disconnect();
  });
```

Then I do `socket.emit('kickout', 'someusersocketid');` on my frontend but it won't work for some reasons. Seems like the server listens to "kickout" alright but so to "kicked". Why is that?

Comment: socket.clients[kickedClientId].send({ event: 'disconnect' });
have you tried this?

Comment: is that server side or client side?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var clients = {}
sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  clients[socket.id] = socket;

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    delete clients[socket.id];
  });
});
```

Comment: is that server side?

Comment: yes @snksaint it's server side code

Comment: thanks. Although I found an alternative solution: `socket.on('kickout', (sckid) => {
   io.sockets.sockets.forEach((socket) => {
    if(socket.id === sckid)
      socket.disconnect(true);
    });
  });`

Comment: How does this code kick someone out?